# Elixir Concatinate key value pair from Map to existing String (FDF file generation)

Tags: dictionary, recursion, functional-programming, elixir, phoenix-framework

beginner at Elixir and functional programming in general.

I'm trying to create a FDF document to fill out existing PDF forms with the library `Pdftk`.

Think I'm going about this the wrong way and using known OOP logic rather than adhering to elixir's.

```
defp generate_fdf(filename, fields) do
    fdf = fdf_header()
    |> fdf_content(fields)

    File.write!("./tmp/test.fdf", fdf_footer(to_string(fdf)))
    IO.puts fdf_footer(to_string(fdf))
  end

  defp fdf_header() do
    "%FDF-1.2\n1 0 obj<</FDF<< /Fields["
  end

  defp fdf_content(file_content, fields) do
    Enum.map fields,  fn {k, v} ->
      file_content <> "\n" <> "<< /T (#{k}) /V (#{v}) >>"
    end
  end

  defp fdf_footer(file_content) do
   file_content <> "\n] >> >>\nendobj\ntrailer\n<</Root 1 0 R>>\n%%EOF"
  end
```

Currently the output of generate_fdf will result in:

```
%FDF-1.2
1 0 obj<</FDF<< /Fields[
<< /T (first_name) /V (George) >>%FDF-1.2
1 0 obj<</FDF<< /Fields[
<< /T (last_name) /V (Das) >>
] >> >>
endobj
trailer
<</Root 1 0 R>>
%%EOF
```

Meaning that `fdf_header()` is present twice.

Thanks in advance. Bonus points if the answer contains recursion and is idiomatic to elixir. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood the question right, the problem is in `fdf_content/2`. You're prepending `file_content` to every field. The following code will only add `file_content` once:

```
defp fdf_content(file_content, fields) do
  file_content <>
    Enum.map_join(fields, "\n", fn {k, v} ->
      "<< /T (#{k}) /V (#{v}) >>"
    end)
end
```